# Is this statement correct: "All structural variations are energy driven"?

Tags: structure, molecular-mechanics, potential-energy-surface

In modelling using molecular mechanics can one state that "all structural variations are energy driven?".

The statement is related to protein-ligand binding in modelling.
Sometimes one can assess system by looking at structural stability on one hand but also on energy values.
If all structure variations are energy driven, I think it makes more sense to focus more on energy than structure.

Comment: I don't understand either. In ambient conditions the structure is "driven" by the free energy, which also includes entropy!

Comment: I might buy that all structural variations are driven by the gradient of the energy...

Comment: @jheindel any literature reference on that?

Comment: @BND no, when someone says "I might buy", it means they don't have a literature reference but they can believe it (although they are not 100% sure). This question can be re-opened if it's modified/improved, **or if someone writes a comment saying that they'd like to answer it**.